# In two tabview populating same data

Tags: c#, wpf, view, datacontext, multiple-instances

I'm new to c#, WPF,

I used Tab Control for showcase two different data table in same Ui,

i.e Tab A and Tab B

In Tab A- displays only gantt view and Tab B- displays only Table view, both are having different data.

When i runs gantt view data display in Table view.

Reason: Binding of Data Context

I'm confused to use multiple DataContext in a application can any one help me out.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace APE.WPF.Controls.DynamicGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //public List<CsvGChart> DataContext1 { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ganttTab();
            tableTab();


        }

        public void ganttTab()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var dataItems = new List<SampleGridItem>();

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    dataItems.Add(
                        new SampleGridItem()
                        {
                            ProductionDate = new DateTime(random.Next(2014, 2014), random.Next(1, 12), random.Next(1, 27)),
                            ProductName = string.Format("10-" + y),
                            ProductionCount = random.Next(1, 2) * random.Next(0, 30)
                        });
                }
            }

            DataContext = dataItems;


        }

        public void tableTab()
        {
            DataContext = FunctionalFun.UI.CsvParseDataService.ReadFile(@"Unit Records Sample.csv");
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `DataContext` with 2 properties, one for the Gantt data and one for the Table data, may be something like that:

```
public class TabViewDataContext
{
    public List<SampleGridItem> GanttData { get; set; }
    public List<CsvGChart> TableData { get; set; }
}
```

and bind each control to the corresponding data context property, the class should look like this:

```
namespace APE.WPF.Controls.DynamicGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //public List<CsvGChart> DataContext1 { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var context = new TabViewDataContext
            {
                GanttData = ganttTab(),
                TableData = tableTab()
            }
            this.DataContext = context;
        }

        public List<SampleGridItem> ganttTab()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var dataItems = new List<SampleGridItem>();

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    dataItems.Add(
                        new SampleGridItem()
                        {
                            ProductionDate = new DateTime(random.Next(2014, 2014), random.Next(1, 12), random.Next(1, 27)),
                            ProductName = string.Format("10-" + y),
                            ProductionCount = random.Next(1, 2) * random.Next(0, 30)
                        });
                }
            }
            return dataItems;
        }

        //Not sure if this should return that type
        public List<CsvGChart> tableTab()
        {
            return FunctionalFun.UI.CsvParseDataService.ReadFile(@"Unit Records Sample.csv");
        }        
    }
}
```